# How to make a function which returns Type <T>

Tags: c#, arraylist, collections, type-conversion

C# .net 4.0

I have created a function which converts ArrayList into List

```
List<MatchBowlDetails> lstBowling = ConvertArrayListToList(BowlingTeamScore).Cast<MatchBowlDetails>().ToList(); 

public static List<Object> ConvertArrayListToList(CollectionClass paramcollection)
    {
        //Function use:
        //This function takes array List and return List<Type>
        //TODO

        return null;
}
```

As you can see here I have created a function which converts `ArrayList` into `List<T>`

Here `BowlingTeamScore` is a collection of `MatchBowlDetails` class and inherited from `CollectionClass` which make `ArrayList` type of collection.

Now here as this function is returning `List<Object>` type of object and I want to return `List<T>` type of `T`, where `T` is `paramCollection.GetType();`

So the new user code will be :

```
List<MatchBallDetails> lstBowling = ConvertArrayListToList<BowlingTeamScore); // here no need to type cast back..
```

Please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public static List<T> ConvertArrayListToList<T>(CollectionClass paramcollection)
{
    return paramcollection.Cast<T>().ToList(); 

}
```